# Which cab file for an HTC Diamond

Tags: windows-mobile

I have an HTC diamond and I’m trying to install an app which gives me 5 choices for .cab files

.PPC.ARM.cab
.PPC.ARMWM.cab
.PPC.MIPS.cab
.PPC.SJ3.cab
.SP.ARM.cab

I think it’s one of the first two, but I’m not sure which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the ones you *don't* want:

- MIPS is an older type of processor that is no longer used in mobile phones.
- SP would specify SmartPhone devices (i.e. no touchscreen but still Windows Mobile)
- SH3 is another type of processor like MIPS that is no longer used.

And then The one you *do* want, (*maybe*):

- ARM is the processor that almost all modern mobile phones are based on, but I'm not conviced about the difference between ARM and ARMWM.  I would suspect that you want the ARMWM cab as Windows Mobile is the shell that is built around the ARM based Windows CE core so I suspect that ARM is for Windows CE without the WinMo interface...

Any info on the app and where to get it?  I may be able to advise better then....

A bit more background reading on the different processor types is [here](http://www.mobilitysite.com/boards/x5-forums/1635-mips-arm-sh3-whast-difference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the .PPC.ARM.cab

Check out http://forum.xda-developers.com/ if you're in the world of HTC WinMo devices.